# Reorder values inside a JSON-embedded string based on a flag's value

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files with different schema.
The sample data in the JSON files as

File1.json

```
{
  "ServiceSettings": {
    "ServiceName": "my-service",
    "RedisSettings": {
      "RedisHost": "HOST-A;HOST-B" 
    }
  }
}
```

File2.json:

```
{
  "RedisHost": "HOST-A;HOST-B"
}
```

I have a requirement as below and the conditions are passed through the pipelines, dynamically

I set a variable preset as

`host_orderA="HOST-A;HOST-B"`
&
`host_orderB="HOST-B;HOST-A"`

1. if the condition is A, the RedisHost should be

   ```
   "RedisHost": "HOST-A;HOST-B"
   ```
2. if the condition is B, the RedisHost should be

   ```
   "RedisHost": "HOST-B;HOST-A"
   ```
3. Irrespective of the order of hosts list HOST-A & HOST-B in the actual JSON files, I want to order the hosts in the JSON and print or output data into a variable or use `sponge` to replace in the same JSON files, based on the conditions, 1 & 2 above.

I tried a few things using sed & JQ but was unable to attain proper output. I prefer to use JQ to replace it as it's JSON-friendly.

Comment: Only use the awk tag if your question is _about_ awk; only use the sed tag if it's _about_ sed, etc; don't tag for tools you only speculate someone _might_ use, if your question isn't about a specific problem with that tool.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you _show us_ your attempt with jq? It's a lot easier to provide an answer that's focused on where you made a mistake if we see what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: (Also, note that we expect input to be in a state where we can copy-and-paste it with no changes whatsoever to test; putting `// comments //` in JSON that doesn't allow comments, or `...`s, &c. is the opposite of helpful).

Comment: Also, you say "if the condition is A", but you don't say anything about how your/our code is supposed to check what "the condition" is. Is there, say, a _variable_ that will be set to either A or B?

Comment: to find the schema first, I tried `jq 'if .RedisHost == null then .[]|.RedisSettings.RedisHost else .RedisHost end'` and used the sed to substitute with predefined conditions and variables set for conditions A & B . With JQ I tried to find but was unable to find the right way of doing it

Comment: [Edit] details on what you tried (in proper [mre] form) into the question, please.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to only output the hosts or do you want to reorder the hosts in the file (and update the files)?

Comment: @knittl, I want to reorder the hosts and print the JSON so that JSON can be used by the apps

Comment: Something else which works great on the command line is Node.js. You write a Javascript program which instantiates an object or array from the data in each of your files, manipulates the data using Javascript’s powerful string and array methods, then serialises it back to new files.

Comment: @VenuReddy but what are the conditions? How do you want to decide if the order should be A or B?

Comment: @knittl - I have set the conditions in the pipelines during the execution

Comment: Part of why we ask for a [mre], btw, is to force you to _show_ things like how the "conditions" you set are represented, vs forcing someone to guess in order to answer your question (which is generally a valid reason to close a question; in the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the bullet point regarding questions that are "unclear or lacking specific details").

Comment: Are you asking about `(..|select(.RedisHost?).RedisHost) = "xyz"`? It sounds like the condition is external to jq and you are only interested in setting the field `RedisHost` regardless of its position/schema.

Comment: @knittl
 Yes, I put all conditions external to JQ just to simplify my work for now. My initial thought was to have it all with jq.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a particularly *clean* solution, but the following works:

```bash
condition=A # or condition=B
jq --arg condition "$condition" '
  def maybeReorderHost:
    ( if $condition == "A" then "HOST-A" else "HOST-B" end) as $priorityPattern |
    if type != "object" then . else (
      if .RedisHost? == null then . else (
        .RedisHost |= (split(";") as $hostArr |
        [[$hostArr[] | select(index($priorityPattern) != null)],
         [$hostArr[] | select(index($priorityPattern) == null)]]
        | add | join(";") )
    ) end
  ) end;

  walk(maybeReorderHost)
' <FileA.json
```

We're using `split(";")` to split your string into an array; filtering for the array elements that *do* match your desired pattern; filtering for the array elements that *don't* match your pattern; and then concatenating those two sublists together.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of `.RedisHost` is fixed, you can try :

```
this=B
jq --arg this $this\
    '(if $this == "A" then "B" else "A" end) as $that|
     (.. | select(type == "object" and has("RedisHost"))
           .RedisHost?) = "HOST-\($this);HOST-\($that)"' File1.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

```
   # To detect the condition at the pipeline level based on the environment 

    detect=< To detect the condition to apply > # more at Pipeline

   # Defining list of host variables

    host_A=HOST-A; host_B=HOST-B

   # construct host order based on $detect 
 
    if [[ $detect =~ A ]]; then order_host="$host_A;$host_B"; elif
       [[ $detect =~ B ]] ; then 
       order_host="$host_B;$host_A" ; else 
       echo "Invalid ";
    fi

   # find the RedisHost and replace it with the constructed order_host

    jq --arg myvar "$order_host" '(..|objects|select(.RedisHost).RedisHost)|=$myvar' File1.json)"
    jq --arg myvar "$order_host" '(..|objects|select(.RedisHost).RedisHost)|=$myvar' File2.json)"
```